# How can I get diff to show only added and deleted lines

Tags: command-line, unix, diff

How can I get the unix command diff show only added and deleted lines?  If diff can't do it, what tool can?

Comment: Are we talking about the unix command diff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible as it will be hard to differentiate between changed, added and deleted lines.

Consider this file:

```
start
old
old
old
end
```

We edit it so it looks like this:

```
start
old
old but now new
new
new
end
```

If we `diff` it we get this output:

```
< old
< old
---
> old but now new
> new
> new
```

This is straightforward to generate.  But if you ask `diff` to only print added and deleted line I think it becomes a matter of opinion which lines have been added and deleted and which have been changed.  For example, did I delete the the last line that said `old` and replace it with a line that said `new` or did I edit it?

Comment: (+1) Agree in principle, but there should be a way to get what diff thinks are the added and deleted lines. To put it another way, show the ouput of `sdiff file1 file2` without the lines that have entries on both sides. If you treat all changed lines as deleted and added lines, you basically get the output of `comm -3 file1 file2`

Answer (score 6):

Does `diff -u0` do what you want?

Comment: The diff on aix doesn't recognize -u0 (unfortunately).

Comment: You *could* install the GNU diff..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question. This function was my solution to obtain the maximum change line number (i.e. changes start with the letter '+'). After which I then loop through the diff file again line by line and do not send to the line processor until this triggers the line to process:

```
#====================================================================
proc_diff_file()    # processes a diff file
#====================================================================
# Arg_1 = Diff File Name
# Arg_2 = New File Name - the one with the new lines
{
  NEW_FILE=$1
  A_FILE=$2
  if [ -f "$A_FILE" ]; then
    echo "processing diff $A_FILE"
    pre_process_diff $A_FILE
    # Set loop separator to end of line
    ndx=0
    BAKIFS=$IFS
    IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
    exec 3<&0
    exec 0<$A_FILE
    while read line
    do
      ndx=$(expr $ndx + 1)
      # use $line variable to process line in processLine() function
      if [ $ndx > $max_ndx ]; then
        proc_age $line
      fi
    done
    exec 0<&3
    # restore $IFS which was used to determine what the field separators are
    IFS=$BAKIFS

#    cleanup $NEW_FILE

    echo "processing diff $A_FILE done"
  fi
}
```

Here is the function:

```
#====================================================================
pre_process_diff()  # pre-processes a diff file for last changed line
                    # sets a variable named $max_ndx
#====================================================================
# Arg_1 = Diff File Name
{
  A_FILE=$1
  max_ndx=
  # collect last line number of diff + 
  # all lines following are new data
  `grep -n "^[+]" $A_FILE | gawk '-F:' '{ print $1 }' >tmp`
  # Set loop separator to end of line
  # read through to the last line number
  BAKIFS=$IFS
  IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
  exec 3<&0
  exec 0<tmp
  while read last_line
  do
    max_ndx=$last_line
  done
  exec 0<&3
  # restore $IFS which was used to determine what the field separators are
  IFS=$BAKIFS
  echo "pre-processing diff $A_FILE done max_ndx=$max_ndx"
}
```

Steve

Comment: Install GNU diff, and use that. AIX' tools are severely outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I find it simplest [to use grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470994/77539):

Added lines:

```
grep -xvFf filea.txt fileb.txt
```

Removed lines:

```
grep -xvFf fileb.txt filea.txt
```

`-x`: match whole lines

`-v`: lines NOT matching the pattern(s)

`-F`: treat patterns as fixed strings, not regular expressions

`-f <otherfile>`: read the list of patterns from a file

Comment: this works great for comparison with current and original package install lists.  Makes it easy to see what has been installed/removed since initial configuration (as least for Arch)