# How can I get a diff-like comparison of two files without the “change” sections?

Tags: command-line, comparison, diff

I have two files that I would like to compare in terms of additions and deletions only. For example, if I diff [these two files](https://superuser.com/a/46809):

```
start
old
old
old
end
```

and:

```
start
old
old but now new
new
new
end
```

I would get this:

```
3,4c3,5
< old
< old
---
> old but now new
> new
> new
```

Rather than the program showing one change, I would like it to show one addition and one deletion. Something like this:

```
3,4d2
< old
< old
3a3,5
> old but now new
> new
> new
```

(This probably isn't valid.)

Is is possible to do this with `diff`, and if not, is there a program that can do it?

Answer (score 0):

use the "side by side" feature of diff:

```
shiny:~ fl$ diff --side-by-side v1 v2
start                           start
old                             old
old                           | old but now new
old                           | new
                              > new
end                             end
```

other excellent options available in a man page near you: `man 1 diff`